# What is the TFM to target .net 6 and Windows Server 2016?

Tags: windows, .net-6.0, windows-server-2016, target-framework

In Visual Studio 2022, The project property window has field to set Target OS version If we choose Target OS. I couldn't find Which number I should choose to target Windows Server 2016 (version 1607). The help link pointing to here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#net-5-os-specific-tfms

Do we have any mapping between OS name and version ?

The available numbers under "Target OS Version" field are 7.0, 8.0, 10.0.17763.0, 10.0.18362.0, 10.0.19041.0, 10.0.20348.0, 10.0.22000.0, 10.0.22621.0

It would be helpful if any authoritative link from Manufacturer Microsoft shared.